# How do you convert an integer into a date (format YYYY) in R

Tags: r

I have a big data set, filled with dates that are in integer form, and different types of integer form (YYYYMMDD, YYYYMM and YYYY)

I just want to get all of them to YYYY.

I first tried splitting up the data frame into three data frames with the different respective date (integer) forms. And then I tried to change the data form from integer to date.

Below is me splitting up the data and then all the various things i have tried and subsequently commented out.

```
Opera_A <- Opera_split$Date_Format_A
Opera_B <- Opera_split$Date_Format_B
Opera_C <- Opera_split$Date_Format_C


lubridate::dmy(Opera_C$Composer_Born)
#as.Date(Opera_C$Composer_Born, "%m/%d/%y")
#Composer_Born_C <- data.frame(Composer_Born)
#Opera_C <- Opera_C %>% mutate(df,dateTime=as.Date(Composer_Born, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
#Opera_C <- transform(Opera_C,Composer_Born=as.Date(as.character(Integer),"%Y%m%d"))
# Opera_C$Composer_Born <- as.Date(Opera_C$Composer_Born, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I keep getting `Error in Opera_C$Composer_Born : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` --- do i have to turn these vectors into dfs or can i just convert them directly?

Any help much appreciated --- I'm an R beginner!

Thank you

Comment: You need to include the example of your data

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, include some data as an example.

Comment: If you want them all `YYYY`, can just do `substr(as.character(x), 1, 4)` since they all start with `YYYY`.

Comment: It's not clear what any of these are: `Opera_A <- Opera_split$Date_Format_A`. Most answers were responses to the headline of your question but if you want any help with your code snippet, you will have to be much more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @caldwellst in the comments you can just pull the first 4 characters if they're all in the format you indicated. Then you can use `as.Date(format = "%Y)` to turn into actual date format and just fill in the M and D portions. Then use `lubridate::year()` to pull the year info.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

c(17701216, 177012, 1770) %>% 
  as.character() %>% 
  str_sub(1, 4) %>% 
  as.Date(format = "%Y") %>% 
  year()
#> [1] 1770 1770 1770
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
> library(anytime)
> anydate(c(20220210, 202202, 2022))
[1] "2022-02-10" "2022-02-01" "2022-01-01"
>
```

However, YYYYMM is not a really date: it is indeterminate as it could be any day of that month, ditto for YYYY.  So `anydate` guesses for you here.

Comment: Thanks for this
I'm getting `Error in install.packages : object 'anytime' not found` though

Comment: Make sure you try it with quotes:  `install.packages("anytime")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be recognized as dates, you could do this:

```
date <- as.numeric(19351225)

as.Date(paste(substr(as.character(date), 1, 4),"-01-01",sep=""),format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Congrats on your first post! A few pointers: 1. omit the commentary about being new 2. format your code appropriately using back ticks `. 3. Demonstrate that your code works by sharing the output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you actually just want an integer indicating the years and all your dates are after the year 1000, then this should work:

```r
years_from_date_int <- function (i) {
  digits <- ceiling(log10(i))
  divide_by <- 10 ** (digits - 4)
  floor(i / divide_by)
}

print(years_from_date_int(10210104))
# [1] 1021
```

It also has the advantage that I don't have to import any libraries and it may be potentially much more efficient as it doesn't have to convert the ints to strings like many of the other answers.

Quick benchmark:

```r
set.seed(12345)
samples <- runif(1000000, min=1000, max = 20200101)

start <- Sys.time()
for (s in samples) {
  years_from_date_int(s)
}
end <- Sys.time()
print("Direct int manipulation:")
print(end - start)

start <- Sys.time()
for (s in samples) {
  years_from_date_int_string_manipulation(s)
}
end <- Sys.time()
print("With string conversion:")
print(end - start)

# [1] "Direct int manipulation:"
# Time difference of 3.928902 secs
# [1] "With string conversion:"
# Time difference of 16.86341 secs
```